# Office map like Indoor map

Tags: android, dictionary

I need to design an indoor map for my office in android application.i need when any person enter in my office then he use my app to reach a particular person from entry gate of my office .is google indoor map fine in my requirements

Comment: have you looked for other options other than google indoor map?? since its has accuracy issues???

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Google Indoor Map and there are many other indoor navigation SDKs available.

Here are a very few of them :

https://estimote.com/indoor/

https://indoo.rs/

https://dev.insiteo.com/

However, if you are just drawing a simple map of your office building, you can easily draw the map using OpenGL on a `GLSurfaceView`. If you are just getting started with OpenGL, Android Training has a great tutorial on it. You can draw your office using basic rectangles and lines. Here's the link to the tutorial :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html